# Nginx Config for ws://<ip>:<port>

Tags: sockets, nginx, websocket, ws

I have a domain i call it `<domain>` and ip call `<ip>` and port `<my-local-port>`, i wan't using nginx on my server (dns binded to my server success), my problem is that reverse proxy ws:// protocole to my server i send my request in two link:

- `https://<ip>:<my-local-port>`
- `ws://<ip>:<my-local-port>`

for https i configurate nginx as:

```
server {
      listen       443;
      server_name  <domain>    www.<domain> ;

      location / {
        proxy_pass       http://localhost:<my-local-port>;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      }
}
```

i bind `https://<domain>` into my local port `<my-local-port>`.

**how can i bind  `ws://<domain>` into local port `<my-local-port>` ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This configuration worked for me:

```
server {
        listen       443;
        server_name  <domain>    www.<domain> ;  

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:<my-local-port>;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;          
        }
}
```

Comment: this configuration bind ws://<domain> to http://127.0.0.1:<my-local-port> ?

Comment: Yes, that's what it does. I use this exact configuration for a project that uses websockets - both the upgrade-from-http type as well as the directly-establish-ws type.