# Live display camera, using websocket and jsmpeg. Connection to ws://my_api:port failed

Tags: canvas, websocket, camera, live, jsmpeg

WebSocket connection to 'ws://my_ip:port/' failed:

1. FE

   import React, {useEffect} from "react";
   import "./App.css";
   import JSMpeg from '@cycjimmy/jsmpeg-player';

const App = () => {

```
useEffect(() => {
    new JSMpeg.VideoElement("#video-canvas", ws://localhost:port, {
            autoplay: true,
        });

}, []);

return (
    <div id="body">
        <div id="title"
            style={{
                display: "flex",
                justifyContent: "center",
                alignItems: "center",
                fontSize: "28px",
                fontWeight: "bold",
                marginTop: "10px",
                marginBottom: "10px",
                color: "blue",
            }}>
            Player stream RTSP
        </div>
        <div id="video" style={{height: "480px", width: "640px"}}/>

    </div>
);
```

};

export default App;

2. BE

```html
const app = require("express")();
const cors = require("cors");
const morgan = require('morgan') ;
Stream = require('node-rtsp-stream')

app.use(cors());
app.use(morgan('dev'));
const streams = {};

const stream_configs = [{
  key: 'kbvision',
  port: 9999,
  url: 'rtsp://user:password@url,
},
];

const stopStream = (port) => {
  if(streams[port]){
    streams[port].stop()
    delete streams[port];
  }
}

app.listen(8080, ()=> {
  console.log("Server running on port 8080 ")
  stream_configs.forEach((config) =>{
    startStream(config.key, config.url, config.port)
  })
})
```

3. RESULT

   VIDEO IS NOT DISPLAYED

Comment: I tried searching for a solution, but none of them helped me. Hope you can help me

Comment: Did you read the link, that i posted (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) ? Please do so and then improve your question. The question is missing a lot of details about the problem, e.g. what is `useEffect()`, what does your browser report about the attempted ws connection, did you configure the ws-server or are you using a public one, ... ?

Comment: I fixed the question and what I did didn't give me an error when I deployed. whether I adjusted http=ws or https=wss

Comment: did you configure the ws-server or are you using a public one?

Comment: Also: please further improve your question. The format is broken (not all code is formatted as code) and there's far too little description of the problem (what server, who configured server, error messages, etc.)

Comment: this is my command, help me

Comment: It works fine when I use ''new WebSocket(`ws://localhost:9999`)''. I got an error while deploying the project, even though I pointed to ''new WebSocket(`ws://my_ip:9999`)'''

Comment: Why are you logging `console.log("Server running on port 8080 ")` when you're actually listening on port `9999`?

Comment: Configuring a server to correctly handle websocket requests is not easy at all. If it works locally, then you're half the way. The rest is about server configuration. Are you using apache, nginx or cloud deployment?

Comment: My coworker created a machine and I vpn came to get the camera stream. But when deploying, it gives an error. Or do you have another way to get camera video like I'm doing without using "ws://my_ip:9999"

Comment: It's difficult to help you when you're not answering to my questions.

Comment: yes i am using nginx, and i am also catching stream from websocket rendering client side. It works fine when I run localhost, but deploying to real environment gives error

Comment: Port 9999 is the open port for the camera, and 8080 is the port that runs for BE. I run on localhost side it still understands that

Comment: Did you configure the deployment nginx server correctly? It requires a reverse proxy.

Comment: This is the configuration that worked for me setting up nginx and websockets: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63084958/nginx-config-for-ws-ipport/63089078#63089078

Comment: It requires a reverse proxy. Do you have any solution for this problem?

Comment: I posted a link to the solution above.

Comment: Do you have any solution for this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71934276/using-cycjimmy-jsmpeg-player-library-doesnt-show-live-camera-video?noredirect=1#comment127111468_71934276

Comment: That question is terribly unspecific. Please read and follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask .

Comment: I have revised the code in the question that I just discussed with you. do you have a way to fix this?

Comment: instead of jsmpeg, in this case i used @cycjimmy/jsmpeg-player', but it shows nothing