# Using @cycjimmy/jsmpeg-player library doesn't show live camera video

Tags: reactjs, camera, live-streaming, ws, jsmpeg

I tried to follow the instructions`

```html
new JSMpeg.VideoElement("#video-canvas", ws://my_ip:port, {
                autoplay: true,
            });
        Show live video  
            <div id="video-canvas" style={{height: "480px", width: "640px"}}></div>
```

`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you for your interest in my question. The error that I encountered was that I could not display the video I wanted, but only had a black screen. While I did all the steps like https://www.npmjs.com/package/@cycjimmy/jsmpeg-player. Looking forward to your help

Comment: Successfully watching the video when I pass a url similar to https://cycjimmy.github.io/staticFiles/media/big_buck_bunny_640x360.ts